# ReactJS security/obfuscation of constants and authed-only routes/scripts

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs, security, authorization

I am developing a ReactJS app with PHP/Apache as a backend REST server. The app will have both public routes as well as private (admin-only) routes. On top of this, I will require to protect data such as Google Maps API premium client ID + secret so I do not want to include this in my app.js.

Is there a standard protocol for providing this security/obfuscation? Does SSR take care of some or all of this? For instance, I do not want to serve the app.js from my admin backend to anyone who is not logged in. While any debugging would not reveal data itself, I do not want to expose things that may indicate aspects of the business model/application. It would seem the obvious thing to do would be to have react router initially pass back a call to the server to check if the user is authorised BEFORE it publishes the app.js bundle. Is this possible?

In the case of Google Map API calls, would the solution be to have a Promise() that calls my server (allowing the server itself to assign the client ID + secret and take care of the request) then wait for the server's response? I assume I would be looking to use [Google's PHP SDK](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/) for this. I am currently playing around with [@google/maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/maps), which requires the client ID + secret when it is required/initialised.

Or do I need to be also running Express.js on my server to cover some of these things?

Hope this question isn't too cumbersome or vague but I am have a hard time finding any real information on how to approach these types of security scenarios with the stack I am using.

Thanks in advance.